# Save dictionary in Excel with Python

Tags: python, pandas

I need your help to save the data in Excel. I`ve parsed some site and I need to input dictionary in Excel.

```
from scrapingbee import ScrapingBeeClient
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

SCRAPINGBEE_API_KEY = "bzzzz"
endpoint = "https://app.scrapingbee.com/api/v1"
pages = [
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/1/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/2/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/3/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/4/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/5/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/6/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/7/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/8/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/9/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/10/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/11/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/12/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/13/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/14/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/15/city:lagos'
    ]

rest = []

#GET_LINKS
for url in pages[:1]:
    params = {
    'api_key': SCRAPINGBEE_API_KEY,
    'url': url}

    response = requests.get(endpoint, params=params)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    body = soup.find_all('h4')
    for items in body:
        item = items.find('a').get('href')
        item_link = 'https://www.businesslist.com.ng' + item
        rest.append(item_link)

#GET_REST

for url in rest[:2]:
    params = {
    'api_key': SCRAPINGBEE_API_KEY,
    'url': url}
    info = {}
    response = requests.get(endpoint, params=params)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    restaraunt_name = soup.find('b', {'id':'company_name'}).text
    info.update({'Restaraunt':restaraunt_name})
    location = soup.find('div', {'class':'text location'}).text.split('View Map')[0]
    info.update({'Location':location})
    phone = soup.find('div', {'class':'text phone'}).text[:11]
    info.update({'Phone':phone})    
    web = soup.find('div', {'class':'text weblinks'}).text
    info.update({'web':web})
    df = pd.DataFrame(info)
    df.to_excel('./Lagos.xlsx')
```

I get the link to parse from list 'rest', then get data from this link. Then I want to save each item from all link to dictionary 'info'. Then save it to Excel file. But code is saving the one line to file, not the all. I`ve missed something.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving df inside the loop with same name it will create only one dict(means each loop value in excel). so you better create a empty dataframe outside the loop and save it into excel file after the loop execution completed.

Your altered code will be like

```
all_info = pd.DataFrame()

for url in rest[:2]:
    params = {
    'api_key': SCRAPINGBEE_API_KEY,
    'url': url}
    info = {}
    response = requests.get(endpoint, params=params)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    restaraunt_name = soup.find('b', {'id':'company_name'}).text
    info.update({'Restaraunt':restaraunt_name})
    location = soup.find('div', {'class':'text location'}).text.split('View Map')[0]
    info.update({'Location':location})
    phone = soup.find('div', {'class':'text phone'}).text[:11]
    info.update({'Phone':phone})
    web = soup.find('div', {'class':'text weblinks'}).text
    info.update({'web':web})
    if len(all_info) == 0:
        all_info = pd.DataFrame(info, index=range(len(info)))
    else:
        all_info = all_info.append(pd.DataFrame(info))
all_info.to_excel('./Lagos.xlsx')
```

Comment: ---> 65 all_info.to_excel('./Lagos.xlsx')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a list with all the data, then converting that to a dataframe and then outputting that to an Excel file.

```py
from scrapingbee import ScrapingBeeClient
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

SCRAPINGBEE_API_KEY = "zzzzzzzzz"
endpoint = "https://app.scrapingbee.com/api/v1"
pages = [
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/1/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/2/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/3/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/4/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/5/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/6/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/7/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/8/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/9/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/10/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/11/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/12/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/13/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/14/city:lagos',
    'https://www.businesslist.com.ng/category/restaurants/15/city:lagos'
    ]

rest = []

#GET_LINKS
for url in pages[:1]:
    params = {
    'api_key': SCRAPINGBEE_API_KEY,
    'url': url}

    response = requests.get(endpoint, params=params)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    body = soup.find_all('h4')
    for items in body:
        item = items.find('a').get('href')
        item_link = 'https://www.businesslist.com.ng' + item
        rest.append(item_link)

#GET_REST
data = []
for url in rest[:2]:
    params = {
    'api_key': SCRAPINGBEE_API_KEY,
    'url': url}
    info = {}
    response = requests.get(endpoint, params=params)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    restaraunt_name = soup.find('b', {'id':'company_name'}).text
    info.update({'Restaraunt':restaraunt_name})
    location = soup.find('div', {'class':'text location'}).text.split('View Map')[0]
    info.update({'Location':location})
    phone = soup.find('div', {'class':'text phone'}).text[:11]
    info.update({'Phone':phone})    
    web = soup.find('div', {'class':'text weblinks'}).text
    info.update({'web':web})
    data.append(info)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_excel('./Lagos.xlsx')
```